# Published pypi package shows up on search but won't pip install

Tags: python, pip, pypi

I have the following issue where my package is published but cannot install:

```
$ pip search "intellimatch"
intellimatch (0.1.0)  - Intelligent matching/textsearch/cli interactivity that works for humans

$ pip install intellimatch
Collecting intellimatch
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement intellimatch (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for intellimatch

$ pip install intellimatch==0.1.0
Collecting intellimatch==0.1.0
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement intellimatch==0.1.0 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for intellimatch==0.1.0
```

It is at https://bitbucket.org/codyc54321/intellimatch

`setup.py` is looking like

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='intellimatch',
    version='0.1.0',
    description='Intelligent matching/textsearch/cli interactivity that works for humans',
    url='https://bitbucket.org/codyc54321/intellimatch',
    author='codyc4321',
    license='MIT',
    packages=['intellimatch'],
    install_requires=[],
    zip_safe=False,
)
```

This is a basic package with 1 folder, `intellimatch`, and no dependencies, just using Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no archive of your project at pypi. See the below steps.

```
$ pip install intellimatch -vvv
```

this will show you a debug traceback.

The url points to https://pypi.python.org/simple/intellimatch/ which has no archive of your package hence it won't download and install your package. Taking from hitchhiker's [guide](http://the-hitchhikers-guide-to-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/contributing.html#uploading-distributions), upload a distribution of your package using the command below.

```
$ python setup.py register sdist upload
```

Comment: Wow, I think you solved it. Network security at my office may have been blocking it or something, I will try this at home and open different question if I fail. Thank you

Comment: `open different question if I fail` love it when people say this

Comment: Well I'd prefer to solve it now :) I'm at work and there's heavy firewalls that I didn't set up and don't understand. Normally I just go home and do things like this and it works

Answer (score 1):

pip downloads packages from PyPI. There is no packages at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/intellimatch hence nothing to download and install.

Give pip a [VCS URL](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#vcs-support):

```
pip install git+https://bitbucket.org/codyc54321/intellimatch/src?egg=intellimatch
```

Comment: Ok ty I will try now, do you know what I need to do to get published normally so `pip install intellimatch` works? I thought the guide I followed does that...

Comment: `$ pip install git+https://bitbucket.org/codyc54321/intellimatch/src?egg=intellimatch
Collecting git+https://bitbucket.org/codyc54321/intellimatch/src?egg=intellimatch
  Cloning https://bitbucket.org/codyc54321/intellimatch/src?egg=intellimatch to /private/var/folders/20/blah/T/pip-blah-build
remote: Not Found
fatal: repository 'https://bitbucket.org/codyc54321/intellimatch/src?egg=intellimatch/' not found
Command "git clone -q https://bitbucket.org/codyc54321/intellimatch/src?egg=intellimatch /private/var/folders/20/blah/T/pip-blah-build" failed with error code 128 in None`

Comment: I've already registered it on pypi and when I log in I see the package

Comment: `pip install git+https://bitbucket.org/codyc54321/intellimatch/src` does work but that's not what I'm wondering

Comment: well if you want to use vcs url then no need to register your package at pypi